# Android 6.0.1 - ZXingScannerView library only White screen displayed when qr code scan

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

When I install the app. using ZXingScannerView library I got unexpected white screen instead of the camera preview.

P.S. run-time permission for the camera guaranteed to open camera from registration screen before going to QR scree. Also, i tried to open it from settings. none of theses work.

Samsung Galaxy S6
OS : Android 6.0.1